# Passing Multiple variables into JSON using ajax and data- off link

Tags: php, ajax, json, variables, dynamic-data

#### Background

I have a web application which uses a link and a jQuery handler to submit information through ajax to perform a function in an outside PHP file....
I am receiving this error on passing the variables

> PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in..... on line 7 (check comment of php)

What exactly am I doing wrong?

#### Link Which is Passing information

```
<a href="#" id="tester" data-letterid="13" data-type="failValidate">This Link Fails</a>
```

#### jQuery

```
$('#tester').on("click",function(){ 
    var dataObj = {}
    dataObj['letterid']=$('#tester').attr("data-letterid");
    dataObj['letterid']=JSON.stringify(dataObj['letterid']);
    dataObj['type']=$('#tester').attr("data-type");
    dataObj['type']=JSON.stringify(dataObj['type']);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'super_testy.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataObj,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert("success!!");

            return false;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus);}
        });});
```

#### PHP File Abstract

```
//It Fails Right Here, and says that Fatal Error, shown above
$id=$_POST('letterid');
$type=$_POST('type');
if ($type == "failValidate") { //do something, etc....}
```

> Even after testing and adding JSON.stringify(xyz) to the variables doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$_POST`, `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST` superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) are *arrays*, so you need to access them with bracket notation, not like a function:

```
$id = $_POST['letterid'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
```

Comment: @hawkhorrow No worries. We all have those days. But take care to read the error first. It mentions a function, yet you know that you don't have any function calls on that line. That's your cue to investigate why PHP thinks that's a function call.

Comment: do you think i'll still need the JSON.stringify though?

Comment: If you use `JSON.stringify` then on the PHP side you'll need to use `json_decode()` to translate the JSON string into an PHP array (or instance of stdclass depending on your optional args). I'd say don't use `JSON.stringify` because its only useful when you need to send an array or an object to the server. You shouldn't stringify primitives.